# When centring a label it goes behind a panel

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the code:

```
Label1.Left = (Me.ClientSize.Width / 2) - (Label1.Width / 2)
```

to center the label, but it seems to hide behind panel1 when I center it, it does not disappear behind it when not centering it.

I have right-clicked the panel and sent to back but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks

Comment: Check what is the actual Parent of Label1. There's a tool named Document Outline, you can find it in `View -> Other Windows` or pressing `CTRL+ALT+T` (if you're using Visual Studio and you're working on a Windows Forms project, that is. Add the appropriate Tags to your question).

Comment: Try `Label1.Parent = Me` followed by `Label1.BringToFront()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Anchor` property for centering the label.

In designer:
Remove all anchors, by default Top and Left anchors are enabled

In code:

```
Label1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None
```

Enabled anchors keep selected distance to the parent boundaries same when parent size is changed.
When opposite anchors are disabled distance to parent's corresponding boundaries will be kept even.